# Merging 2 json objects using a common id with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, merge

I have 2 bits of json:

```
[
    { "my-id": "123re4",
      "file-path": "3:1/test.png"
    },
    { "my-id": "23gf45",
      "file-path": "3:5/test2.gif"
    }
]
```

and

```
[
    { "my-id": "123re4",
      "status": 0
    },
    { "my-id": "23gf45",
      "status": 0
    }
]
```

They are both holding information about the same list of items, each of which is identified with a unique id 'my-id'. I want to combine them with jquery so that I end up with a merged json object like this:

```
[
    { "my-id": "123re4",
      "file-path": "3:1/test.png",
      "status": 0
    },
    { "my-id": "23gf45",
      "file-path": "3:5/test2.gif",
      "status": 0
    }
]
```

Anyone know the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

`var object3 = $.extend({}, object1, object2);`

this will do the merging.. if the another object with the same iD is found the its overwritten.
[refer here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for more

you can also merge 
`$.extend(object1, object2);` this merges object2 into object1.

I'd recommend using the 1st approach. (coz its easier to read and understand)

Comment: by using the first approach the original objects remains unchanged